# How do you bitwise invert all the values if a register in Thumb - 2 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

The question above^
How do you bitwise invert all the values in a register in Thumb - 2 assembly?
I havent been able to find the instruction for this anywhere

Comment: Do you mean **in** a register? `MVN`?

Comment: Look at C compiler output for `int f(int x) {return ~x;}`.  https://godbolt.org/z/hYxP7c.  If you don't know how to do something in asm for a given ISA (or aren't sure you know an efficient way), ask a compiler.

Comment: @Jester `MVNS` has a shorter encoding.

Comment: are you specifically wanting the thumb2 instruction/encoding or something that runs on a thumb capable machine?  what assembler are you using and what is your target core?  there is a thumb and for armv7-m/a there is a thumb2 version.